# How to interact with a CLI program using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Imagine I have a program writen in whatever language and compiled to run interactivelly using just command line interface. Lets imagine this one just for the sake of simplify the question:

- The program first asks the user its name.
- Then based on some business logic, it may ask the user age OR the user email. Only one of those.
- After that it finishes with success or error.

Now image that I want to write a script in powershell that fills all that data automatically.

How can I achieve this? How can I run this program, read its questions (outputs) and then provide the correct answer (input)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the questions it will ask ahead of time, this would be tough.

PowerShell scripts are normally linear.  Once you start the program from in PowerShell, it would wait for the program to finish before continuing.  There are ways to do things in parallel, but it doesn't interact like that.

Although if you're dealing with something like a website making the first call gives a response (completing the command).  You could match the response to select the proper value.

Or if the program is local and allows command line parameters, you could do that.

Comment: Thanks but lets imagine the program I gave as example for the sake of simplicity. Web is far beyond my context.